# Adding a dependency to a class of targets in GNU make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a naming convention that indicates that some executables depend on additional objects, e.g., targets of the form `foo_test` depend on `foo_test.o` and `unit_tests.o`. Is it possible to specify a general rule in GNU make to capture this convention?

I tried the obvious, but it seems to have no effect:

```
%_test: unit_tests.o
```

Comment: What rules do you use? Do you have a separate rule for each target, or a pattern rule, or a pattern rule specific to that class, or do you rely on the built-in implicit rules, or different approaches for different targets in the class, or what?

Comment: In this case, I rely on the default rule and `$(CFLAGS)` etc. Then I separately specify `foo_test bar_test baz_test: unit_tests.o` and the default rule does the right thing. I'm looking for a way to avoid having to add files to that line every time I make new unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the pattern specifier (`%`) in both the target and one of its dependencies, and of course also specify the commands for the rule to make the target:

```
%_test: %_test.o unit_test.o
    cc -o $@ $?
```

Comment: When using GNU make, I would use $(LINK.c) as the linker command.

Comment: I'm not looking to redefine a rule. I'm only looking to specify dependencies. If I do what you're proposing, I'd have to have a different rule for all other linkage targets, and make sure they don't diverge. For example, the way you have your rule, it would ignore `$(LDLIBS)`. The default linkage recipe honors it. So for binaries whose names don't add in `_test`, the linking command would be different.

Comment: What @ndim said....  I.e. use the appropriate pre-defined variables as used in the builtin rules.  Choose appropriately from what you see with `make -p`.